# Laravel. Изменить структуру

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Установил laravel с помощью composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name
```

Для чистоты разработки я изменил структуру проекта до такого вида

```
project_name/laravel/
project_name/vendor/
project_name/public/
project_name/composer.json
```

В папку project_name/laravel/ я переместил все файлы и папки самого laravel.

Файл composer.json привел к такому виду:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "laravel/",
            "laravel/database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "laravel/app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "laravel/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('laravel/.env.example', 'laravel/.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php laravel/artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php laravel/artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php laravel/artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

При запуске composer install выдает ошибку

```
Script php laravel/artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Где еще поправить пути?

Answer (score 2):

А в `bootstrap/autoload.php` поправили путь к вендор?

`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`